# Android app connection with firebase real time database failure error

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Tried to connect firebase realtime database with my android app and updated firebase gradle files, since then this error causes my app to crash, HELP:

```
2021-06-19 12:47:52.128 23038-23038/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.drowsinessdetection, PID: 23038
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite; in class Ljava/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory' appears in /apex/com.android.runtime/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscovery.discoverLazy(ComponentDiscovery.java:112)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(FirebaseApp.java:418)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:299)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:267)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(FirebaseApp.java:252)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(FirebaseInitProvider.java:51)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2154)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:2128)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(FirebaseInitProvider.java:45)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7294)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6765)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6615)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:232)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1953)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950
```

[build.gradle(app) config & firebase versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYG6e.png)

Comment: just updated with config and the firebase version

Comment: Hi have you tried firebase-bom https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup   `implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.1.0')`  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'` `implementation 
 com.google.firebase:firebase-database'`

Comment: I did not have firebase-bom in my gradle but I did have other implementations added, I tried the firebase-bom as you suggested but it still shows the same error.

Comment: Hi, where are you calling `Firebase.initialize(this)`?

Comment: in my RegisterUser class

Comment: can you please tell me what this error means, I dont understand it

Comment: Hi, please comment this line `Firebase.initialize(this)` and see if it's working

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help but it turns out my Android Studio was stuck at v4.0.2 or maybe corrupted and that was one of the major reasons it was throwing out errors. Just did a forced update on it and now it's all working perfectly!